# Can any Hamiltonian be expressed as a sum of free and pair-interaction terms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, hamiltonian, interactions

Consider a number of systems $\{S_i\}$ with a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}=\otimes_i\mathcal{H}_{S_i}$. Consider an arbitrary Hamiltonian $H$ defined on this Hilbert space. Can this arbitrary Hamiltonian be defined as a sum of free and pair-interaction terms?

A free term is one which acts as the identity on all Hilbert subspaces $\mathcal{H}_i$ but one $\mathcal{H}_k$:
$$H_{free}= \otimes_{i\neq k} 1_{S_i} \otimes H_{S_k}$$

An interaction term is one which as the identity on all Hilbert subspaces, but two subspaces ($\mathcal{H_j \otimes H_k}$), and cannot be written as a sum of free terms:
$$H_{int}= \otimes_{i\neq j, k} 1_{S_i} \otimes H_{S_j \cup S_k}$$

Note: I am only interested in non-relativistic Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: What about three particle interactions?

Comment: That’s exactly one of the problems at stake: whether interaction terms which involve three systems may be decomposed into pair-interactions. I should note (and I have added to the question): I am only interested in non-relativistic quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible, as can be seen immediately by parameter counting.

(For $N$ sites, there is $N$ one-body and $N(N-1)/2$ two-body terms, and each of them can be specified with a fixed number of parameter. On the other hand, the most general Hamiltonian has $d^N$ parameters.)

Comment: That makes sense. I am assuming $d$ is the dimensions of the Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_{S_i}$ (assuming they are all the same dimension)?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that the thing which really matters is the scaling (exponential vs. quadratic), not the precise numbers.

Comment: Definitely, true. Thanks!